# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..7, inclusive: 8

Tags: json, listview, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to display all the values from retrieved from an API request.

Here's what it's showing at the moment:

[image: Text]

I'm using a listview builder for the page. The JSON can be retrieved from this link: [Here](https://90d53c1e-1ca3-4d5e-982e-0ff81a3ba7f5.mock.pstmn.io/profile/questions)

This is my entire code for the page: [Code](https://dartpad.dev/e57b6545b307accafdd8bfe7b11e43f0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your ListViewBuilder:

```
ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: _ListFamilyPageState.data.body.family.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Container(
        height: 74.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0),
              bottomRight: const Radius.circular(20.0)),
        ),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50.0,
        child: Center(
            child: Text(
              data.body.friends[index].id.toString(),
              style:
              TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
            )));
  },
)
```

You specified that there are `family.length` items (in your data: 15),
but you are pulling actual data from `friends[index]` (8 items in your data).

This gives you RangeError when rendering item at index 8.

On top of that: you use static data in your state:

```
class _ListFamilyPageState extends State<ListFamily> {
  static Relations data;
  // ...
}
```

Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

You've set the itemCount attribute of the ListView with _ListFamilyPageState.data.body.family.length and you've use the index of it's builder with another list data.body.friends[index].id.toString()

I don't think both have the same number of elements